# Rails, "undefined method `variant' for nil:NilClass" on render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to do something really simple, render a json with some stuff.
I do have a view views/api/initialize.html.erb if this counts as useful info.
I have no idea what causes this but the variables filled alright, I checked

My controller:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
    def initialize

        @articles = Article.all
        @areas = Area.all
        @languages = Language.all
        data_json = { articles: @articles, areas: @areas, languages: @languages }

        render json: data_json


    end

    def index

    end

end
```

My route:

> get '/init', controller: 'api', action: 'initialize'

Here is my full error trace from development.log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `variant' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/api_controller.rb:9:in `initialize'
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (14.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (44.1ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated. Please change `Mime::HTML` to `Mime[:html]`. (called from const_missing at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:52)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated. Please change `Mime::WEB_CONSOLE_V2` to `Mime[:web_console_v2]`. (called from const_missing at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:52)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (36.5ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (59.3ms)
```

Can you locate where the problem is here?
Thank you.

Comment: try: `get '/init' => 'api#initialize'`

Comment: @7urkm3n Nope, the same exactly. :( It doesn't seem to be a fault at routes.

Comment: try just change method name like `test_initialize`....

Comment: Make this an answer so I can mark it correct, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initailize probably reserved already by Ruby. Just change something not reserved names like `test_api_initialize` or better `api_init`.

```
def api_inits
end
```

routes:

```
get '/init' => 'api#api_inits', as: :init
```